# Differentiating ints and floats with Scala Combinator Parsers

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I've been having an issue getting the scala combinator parsers (specifically the RegexParsers via JavaTokenParsers) deciding between ints and floats.  I must be missing something really basic here, since I can't seem to find any mention of this particular issue anywhere.  I've included a spec with the parser code in question (minus includes, of course).

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SandboxSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchersForJUnit {

  sealed trait PropertyValue

  case class IntValue(value: Int) extends PropertyValue
  case class RealValue(value: Float) extends PropertyValue

  class Parser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def propertyLiteral : Parser[PropertyValue] = intValue | realValue

    def realValue  = floatingPointNumber ^^ {
      s => RealValue(s.toFloat)
    }

    def intValue  = wholeNumber ^^ {
      s => IntValue(s.toInt)
    }
  }

  "A java token parser" should "parse a float" in {
    val p = new Parser()

    val result = p.parseAll(p.propertyLiteral, "5.4") match {
      case p.Success(x, _) => x
      case p.NoSuccess(msg, _) => fail(msg)
    }

    result should be(RealValue(5.4f))

  }
}
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
string matching regex `\z' expected but `.' found
```

One thought, based this [thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3627), I placed a `<~ not(not('.'))` after the wholeNumber, but this didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - the only thing you need to change is `not(not('.'))` to `not('.')`. Why?

The problem is that `intValue` always consumes the part before the dot. If you now write `x ~ '.'` you check if a dot follows and consume it together with the part before the dot. But you want to consume when a dot does not follow, thus you have to write `x ~ not('.')`.

When you write `x ~ not(not('.'))` you have a double negation which is identical to no negation. The only difference here is that such a double negation allows you to lookup the next input without consuming it. That is because on a failure the input is not consumed in order to allow the following parser to parse it again. With a double failure you neither consume anything, but achieve the already mentioned lookup.

Comment: I knew it was something simple, it was just passing me by... Thanks!